# How to make squash file system read-write

Tags: linux, filesystems, squashfs

My **RTL8196EU** Realtek board having read-only squash file system. How do I make this file system Read-Write.

I have tried mount command

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

But its not fixing the problem.

Help me make a Read-Write squash fs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. squashfs is inherently read-only.

If you want to upload new files, you'll need to create and mount a separate read-write filesystem. If you want to modify the existing files, you'll need to create and (carefully!!) upload a replacement filesystem image.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you can't mount a squashfs filesystem as read-write.  There is however still a way to modify the contents.  You will need the `squashfs` or `squashfs-tools` package for the `[un|mk]squashfs` tools.

As root, copy `filesystem.squashfs` to some empty dir, e.g.:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ cp /[path]/[filesystem.squashfs] /tmp/foo
$ cd /tmp/foo
```

Unpack the squashfs-file:

```
$ unsquashfs [filesystem.squashfs]
```

Enter the `squashfs-root` directory and modify it to you liking and then recreate `filesystem.squashfs`:

```
$ cd /tmp/foo
# Do your thing here
$ mksquashfs squashfs-root [filesystem.squashfs] -comp xz
```

Copy the newly created `filesystem.squashfs` over the existing one.

```
$ cp /tmp/foo/[filesystem.squashfs] /[path]/
```

Answer (score 0):

Squashfs is readonly.   Because the entire filesystem is compressed and zipped, before it is written to the storage media.   And so making any changes to any files, it will have to be zipped and rewritten to the entire partition again - which is a great waste of effort if done repeatedly.   And if the entire filesystem cannot fit into the memory you will need a separate holding storage area to store the intermediate files during compression/decompression - taking up even more unnecessary storage space.